# Request handling in node.js with IO from oracledb via knex.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, knex.js

I was wondering: `Node` uses event loop architecture. I connect to my `oracle` RDBMS via `knex` and query the DB with each request. Since oracle doesn't have reactive drivers, can the event loop architecture handle a production scale amount of requests? In any case, whether yes or no, how is it different from reactive drivers like `mongo` offers?

Comment: Can you point us to the "reactive driver" you're using with Mongo? Tell us a bit more about your use case - how are you using the reactive driver? Oracle Database has a queuing framework called Advanced Queuing and means of reacting to changes in data, such as Query Change Notification. While the Node.js driver doesn't have direct support for these features yet (the plan is to add direct support) it's easy enough to set up a web server in Node.js that the database can call out to. I talk about this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPz3VY_0bXE

Comment: @DanMcGhan  Sorry, but my question is rather more abstract, and I'm not interested in implementation details. I should clarify that by `reactive` I meant `async` and `non-blocking`. I come from java world and It seems that java has a distinction between these two, while node has no such distinction. Am I correct?

Comment: Pretty much all the libraries doing any IO like networking are async by default in Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node.js driver for Oracle Database is completely asynchronous/non-blocking. All of its async operations are done using Node.js' thread pool so as not to block the main thread. You might find this recent talk I did interesting (it's my latest attempt at explaining a lot of this stuff): [Understanding Asynchronous Processing and Patterns in Node js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAdeljxq_hs&t=0s&list=PL_lVOJzXeE__1Kh3ko0F-39-cpNLPXbJL&index=1).

Also, I recently started a series on building a REST API with Node.js on Oracle Database. The part on [Database Basics](https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-database-basics/) touches on some of this too.